# how to correctly use format string python

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to use the format string from python with this.

```
values = f'''{
          "sourceId": "{merchant['siteId']}",
          "programId": "{merchant['id']}"
        }'''
```

but I'm getting invalid format specifier.
any idea how to use it correctly in this situation?

Comment: Maybe creating a `dict` and serialize it would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one more curly braces to make it work as a normal string

```py
values = f'''{{
  "sourceId": "{merchant['siteId']}",
  "programId": "{merchant['id']}"
}}'''
```

For example:

```py
merchant = {
    'siteId': 1,
    'id': 2
}

values = f'''{{
  "sourceId": "{merchant['siteId']}",
  "programId": "{merchant['id']}"
}}'''
print(values)
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "sourceId": "1",
  "programId": "2"
}
```